# How to make card responsive using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have section which contain botstrap 4 card div and  pararagraph , I want to be resposnsive,

Here is HTML:

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="marketing-main-page-content_details">
<div class="marketing-main-page-content_details-card">

<div class="marketing-main-page-content_card card " data-related="details2" id="card2">
         <p>Która jest własciawa osoba</p>
      </div>
      </div>

<div class="marketing-main-page-content_description-right" id="details1">
      <div class="title-right">
         <p>Która 1 jest własciawa osoba</p>
      </div>
      <p>To ten kurs jest dla Ciebie, specjalnie dla Ciebie.
         Potem dalsza część tekstu, która ma przekonać do
         zakupu. Przekonany? No to klikamy poniżej i
         lecimy do formularza zamówienia!
      </p>
      <div class="marketing-main-page-content_description-right_button">
         <button type="button" class="marketing-main-page-content_description-right_button-primary">Dowiedz
         się wiecej</button>
      </div>
   </div>

   </div>
```

Here is css

```
.marketing-main-page-content_details {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.marketing-main-page-content_card {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #707070;
}

.marketing-main-page-content_card {
    width: 536px;
    height: 137px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 13px #5C5C5C;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 13px #5C5C5C;
}

.marketing-main-page-content_description-right {
    width: 47%;
    margin-top: 78px;
}

.title-right {
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #707070;
}

.marketing-main-page-content_description-right p {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    margin-top: 28px;
    color: #707070;
    font-weight: normal;
}



.marketing-main-page-content_description-right p {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    margin-top: 28px;
    color: #707070;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.marketing-main-page-content_description-right {
    width: 47%;
    margin-top: 78px;
}
```

Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/a5e4d7u3/25/

Iwould like it to be responsive but right now as you can see in jsfidle its not responsive,

what do I need to change in my code to make it repsonsive?

Comment: This may help - [BS4 grid responsive-classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#responsive-classes)

Comment: its not possible using flexbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to read ["A Complete Guide to Flexbox"](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to understand, how Flexbox works. The [`display: flex;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) rule always applies to the container of the items you want to align. I added a [`min-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width) to your cards container to give it an equal width like the right container.

Also I removed the fixed `width` rules and lots of redundant code in your CSS. Always make sure, that your markup is valid. This should be a responsive working example:

```css
.marketing-main-page-content_details {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.marketing-main-page-content_details-card {
  min-width: 50%;
}

.marketing-main-page-content_card {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #707070;
  height: 137px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 13px #5C5C5C;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 13px #5C5C5C;
}

.title-right {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #707070;
}

.marketing-main-page-content_description-right p {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  margin-top: 28px;
  color: #707070;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="marketing-main-page-content_details">
  <div class="marketing-main-page-content_details-card">

    <div class="marketing-main-page-content_card card " data-related="details2" id="card2">
      <p>Która jest własciawa osoba</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="marketing-main-page-content_description-right" id="details1">
    <div class="title-right">
      <p>Która 1 jest własciawa osoba</p>
    </div>
    <p>To ten kurs jest dla Ciebie, specjalnie dla Ciebie. Potem dalsza część tekstu, która ma przekonać do zakupu. Przekonany? No to klikamy poniżej i lecimy do formularza zamówienia!
    </p>
    <div class="marketing-main-page-content_description-right_button">
      <button type="button" class="marketing-main-page-content_description-right_button-primary">Dowiedz
         się wiecej</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```